# Catch Rest Exception on Client

Tags: java, rest

I have an exception that I throw from the server side that I wish to catch on the client side. The exception should be sent over REST using Jersey. This is what I have so far:

Define my Exception:

```
public class MyException extends Exception implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyException () {
        super();
    }
    public MyException (String msg)   {
        super(msg);
    }
    public MyException (String msg, Exception e)  {
        super(msg, e);
    }
}
```

Define my exception in a class which implements the ExceptionMapper:

```
@Provider
public class TestMapper implements ExceptionMapper<MyException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(MyExceptionexception){
        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(exception.getMessage()).build(); 
    }
}
```

This is my resource class, where the request from the server goes into:

```
@PUT
@Path("calculate")
public void calculateMethod(String id) throws MyException{
   //Other code...
    throw new MyException("custom error message string");
    }       
}
```

And finally, from the client side makes the REST call as follows:

```
public void calculateMethodClient(String id) throws MyException{
    client().put("/test/", "calculate", id);
}
```

When this client method gets called, I have surrounded with Try/Catch to test:

```
public boolean testClient(){
    try {
        client.calculateMethodClient((String) id);
        return true;
    } catch (MyException) {
        return false;
    } catch (UniformInterfaceException e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have put a breakpoint in both catch blocks but it only ever hits the `UniformInterfaceException` catch. This is not what I want as the server side can fail for a variety of reasons and I want to be able to define the error message in 'MyException' each time.

Could someone please explain how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the status code at the client side, and if its a bad request, then throw the exception there along with the exception message that you got from the server.

Comment: The status code always comes back as 500 and there is no way to differentiate between the messages that come back. The toResponse method in TestMapper never seems to get called. Is there something I need to do to get this to work? Surely it should be sending a 400 for a Bad Request instead of 500

Comment: You can use status code to identify good response from the bad one. If its a bad one, throw the exception in your client code.

Comment: But thats not what I want. The server does some calculations and can fail for a number of reasons. I wanted to return this reason to the client from the server.

Comment: That reason for failure can be passed back to the client in the form of the message. The status code (of say BAD REQUEST) would indicate failure.

Comment: But as stated above, it doesn't pass back the BAD REQUEST. It only passes back a generic 500 SERVER ERROR so I have no way of differentiating between the errors. Which makes me think my TestMapper class is defined in the wrong place/incorrect etc...

Comment: Do not throw exception at the server side, else it will always return back 500 (which means server error). Just return the response with the error code and the error message.

Comment: I think what im trying to say is that the error message defined in my exception never gets returned to the client

Comment: Use WebApplicationException catch part